# Area of loop in graph

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

The graph of

$$r = \frac{3\sec(θ)\tan(θ)}{1 + \tan^3(θ)}$$ is shown below. Find the area of the loop.

[image]

I know that the equation for finding the area enclosed under a polar curve is A = (1/2) ∫[a, b] [r(θ)]^2 dθ where r(θ) is the polar equation of the curve and [a, b] represents the interval of θ values that correspond to the desired region, but I am unsure about how I can find the values of a and b in the case of this graph. I think the equation is kind of daunting. And I'm honestly not even sure if that integral can apply to a case like this.

Could I have some help?

Comment: Are you familiar with integration in polar coordinates? Please give some context so we can understand what you familiar with, and what exactly you are stuck on.

Comment: Notice that there's an specific section in [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) called *Avoid "no clue" questions*: "Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts. Such questions will most of the time be rejected by the community, which represents a significant waste of time.."

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with that. I'm just not sure how to use the equations/integrals for the area of polar equations in the case of this problem, like what the values would be.

Comment: I know the area enclosed by a polar curve is A = (1/2) ∫[a, b] [r(θ)]^2 dθ where r(θ) is the polar equation of the curve and [a, b] represents the interval of θ values that correspond to the desired region.

Comment: You could also use the parameterization in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640490/area-under-folium-of-descartes/) instead of polar coordinates. Anyway, you want the area of the closed loop, so you should start by determining where the curve self-intersects. (Obviously at the origin, but what values of $\theta$ make this so?)

Comment: Oh! After doing some further research, I saw an equation that stated the area of the loop would be 3a^2/2, so in this case it would be 3sec^2()/2, but what would be the  value? And also I believe that the values of πn will make the curve self-intersect.

Comment: the Cartesian form of the above graph can be written as $x^3+y^3=3x$,

Comment: From [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wdtdv59ont) integrate on $0\le \theta\le \frac\pi2$

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @cindy, look at [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sqgf6i9pxt) which contains not only the graph but also the result of the loop’s area.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First determine where the curve self-intersects. Remember that in polar coordinates, $r$ is an indication of distance from the origin. From the plot, it's evident that the origin is where the self-intersection occurs, hence when $r=0$. Solve for $\theta$:
$$\frac{3 \sec\theta \tan\theta}{1 + \tan^3\theta} = 0 \implies \sec\theta \tan \theta = 0 \implies \sin\theta=0 \implies \theta=n\pi,n\in\Bbb Z$$
which initially suggests $(a,b)$ should be an interval of length $\pi$, say $(0,\pi)$. However, we also observe that
$$1+\tan^3\theta=0 \implies\tan^3\theta=-1 \implies \tan\theta =-1 \implies \theta=-\frac\pi4+n\pi$$
which means $r(\theta)$ is undefined if $\theta=\dfrac{3\pi}4$. Indeed, one draws the entire curve by letting $\theta\in\left(-\dfrac\pi4,\dfrac{3\pi}4\right)$.

The area must be finite, so we look for a removable discontinuity $r=\theta^*$ in our interval for which $\displaystyle\lim_{\theta\to\theta^*}r(\theta)=0$. Given that $\tan\dfrac\pi2$ is undefined, we can start our search there and luck out immediately, since

$$\lim_{\theta\to\frac\pi2} \frac{3\sec\theta\tan\theta}{1+\tan^3\theta} = \lim_{\theta\to\frac\pi2} \frac{3\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\sin^3\theta+\cos^3\theta} = 0$$

and hence the integral for the loop's area is

$$\frac12\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \frac{9\sec^2\theta\tan^2\theta}{\left(1+\tan^3\theta\right)^2}\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac12\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \frac{3\,\mathrm d\!\left(1+\tan^3\theta\right)}{\left(1+\tan^3\theta\right)^2}=\\[3pt]=\frac12\left[\frac{-3}{1+\tan^3\theta}\right]_0^{\tfrac\pi2}=\frac32\,.$$

Comment: "From the plot, it's evident that the origin is where the self-intersection occurs" Never ever in my life was it okay to argue something like that by "looking at the plot".

Comment: @infinitezero: Then you should object to the question in the first place. It uses the words "the loop" and "shown below". Are you supposed to look at the diagram in the question, or not? If not, then please tell me what is your definition of "loop" in 100% rigorous mathematical terms and give your own solution based on that.

Comment: You can certianly look at the diagram but all my math instructors would have substracted points if my sole reasoning was that the intersection is in the origin based on the plot.

Comment: I agree, it's a bit of a hand-wavy explanation. I was eager to get to the "meat" of the question. To address that, I would point to Piquito's conversion to Cartesian and observing the origin indeed satisfies the curve's equation.

Answer (score 6):

Another way of calculation.

Changing to cartesian coordinates we have $x^3+y^3=3xy$ which gives a nodal cubic symmetric respect to the diagonal $y=x$. In order of calculate easier the integral we change of cartesian rotation of an angle of $-45^{\circ}$ so we have
$$x=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(x'+y')\\y=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(x'-y'))$$ so we get the new equation
$$\sqrt2(2x^3+6xy^2)=6(x^2-y^2)\iff y^2=\dfrac{3x^3-\sqrt2 x^3}{3\sqrt2x+3}$$ symmetric respect to the x-axis. Thus the area is
$$2\int_0^{\dfrac{3}{\sqrt2}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3x^2-\sqrt2 x^3}}{\sqrt{3\sqrt2x+3}}\right)dx=\frac32$$