# How to calculate the area of the region enclosed by $x^3+y^3=3axy$？

Tags: integration, curves, greens-theorem

Let $y=tx,$ after calculation, I get
$$x=\frac{3at}{1+t^3}, y=\frac{3at^2}{1+t^3}.$$
Use the Green Formula, the area is equal to
$$\frac{1}{2}\oint_{\Gamma}xdy-ydx.$$
My question is: how to determine the range of $t$? If I don’t use a drawing software, I wouldn’t even know what this curve looks like. How to determine the range of $t$ for the closed curve on the graph？[image]

Thanks for advance！

Comment: How about expressing the equation in polar coordinate? i.e., Let $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin \theta$.

Comment: As long as you can express the equation in the form $r= f(\theta)$, there is a close form formula for the area, namely $A = \frac{1}{2} \int _{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} r^2 d\theta$.

Comment: It looks like the intersection point is at (0,0). what values of $t$ would give this? $t=0$ is obvious; less obvious is that any positive $t$ will give a point on the looped portion (since $x$ and $y$ are both positive). Consider what $t$ would have to be to get a point on the portion of the curve with $y<0$. Is this even possible? What might this all suggest about the upper limit for $t$ in your integral?

Comment: I calculated it, then $r=\frac{\cos\theta\sin\theta}{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)(1-\cos\theta\sin\theta)}$. It's too complex.@DannyPak-KeungChan

Comment: I'd also add that we can be sure that (0,0) is the point of intersection by considering symmetry. The implicit form of the equation is clearly symmetric across the line $y=x$. If the curve is one continuous curve, this forces at least one point of the form (z,z). Letting $x=y=z$ gives $z=0$ or $z=3a/2$. One of these must correspond to the intersection point (why?). The only real trick here is establishing that the equation represents one continuous curve. At the moment, I don't have a suggestion for that bit.

Comment: If you don't need to use Green's theorem, you may [rotate the plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640490/area-under-folium-of-descartes/), so that the curve is parameterized by $(x,y) = \dfrac{3a}{\sqrt2}\left(\dfrac{t^2-t}{t^3+1}, \dfrac{t^2+t}{t^3+1}\right)$. The loop of the folium is traced out for $t\ge0$; the top of the loop is attained at $t=1$. Then the area you want is$$\int_0^\infty y(t) \frac{dx(t)}{dt} \, dt = 2 \int_0^1 y(t) \frac{dx(t)}{dt} \, dt$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let us show that for any angle $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$, there is a unique $r(\theta) > 0$ such that $x^3 + y^3 = 3axy$ (I assume $a > 0$) with $x = r(\theta)\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r(\theta)\sin(\theta)$. Indeed, such an $r$ should verify the following equation,
$$
r^3(\cos^3(\theta) + \sin^3(\theta)) = 3ar^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta).
$$
It easily gives $r(\theta) = 3a\frac{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{\cos^3(\theta) + \sin^3(\theta)} > 0$. We deduce that the part of the curve in the upper right part of the plane is parametrized by the curve,
$$
\gamma : \theta \mapsto (r(\theta)\cos(\theta),r(\theta)\sin(\theta)),
$$
with $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2}$. You dedcue that,
$$
x(\theta) = r(\theta)\cos(\theta) = 3a\frac{\cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{\cos^3(\theta) + \sin^3(\theta)} = 3a\frac{\tan(\theta)}{1 + \tan^3(\theta)},
$$
and similarly $y = 3a\frac{\tan^2(\theta)}{1 + \tan^3(\theta)}$. To obtain the wanted parametrization, set $t = \tan(\theta)$. Since $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $t$ varies from $0$ to $+\infty$. And,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}(xdy - ydx) & = \frac{1}{2}(x(t)y'(t) - y(t)x'(t))dt\\
& = \frac{9a^2}{2}\left(\frac{t}{1 + t^3}\frac{2t(1 + t^3) - t^2 \cdot 3t^2}{(1 + t^3)^2} - \frac{t^2}{1 + t^3}\frac{1 + t^3 - t \cdot 3t^2}{(1 + t^3)^2}\right)dt\\
& = \frac{9a^2}{2}\frac{-t^5 + 2t^2 + 2t^5 - t^2}{(1 + t^3)^3}dt\\
& = \frac{9a^2}{2}\frac{t^5 + t^2}{(1 + t^3)^3}dt\\
& = \frac{9a^2}{2}\frac{t^2}{(1 + t^3)^2}dt.
\end{align*}
Notice that you could have used $xdy$ or $-ydx$ instead (by Stoke's theorem). Finally,
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Area}(\Omega) & = \frac{9a^2}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^2}{(1 + t^3)^2}dt\\
& = \frac{9a^2}{2}\left[-\frac{1}{3(t^3 + 1)}\right]_0^\infty\\
& = \frac{3a^2}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I did this calculation numerically in the complex plane with $A=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\Im\{z^*\dot z\} dt$ and concur with your result.